# Aggregating error messages in SQL Server procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling

Stored procedures allow for better abstraction and separation of concerns from an application point of view. At my company, there is a tradition of having DBAs write procedures and do all the DB work. And, it is a model that works, mostly.

As a .NET developer, I use Resource files to aggregate all my error/success/validation messages. This allows me keep my error messages standardized and centralized, so, once the implementation is done and we need to document the "application messages", the process is straight-forward.

However, our DBAs have a bad habit of scattering error messages throughout the procedures which makes it difficult to document a system. The current solution is to always return `@Result` and `@Message` and use the Redgate tools to do search and find for those variables. However, this is tedious and it doesn't sound like a great solution.

I was wondering if there are any recommended practices to centralize the error messages on the database side, while still not degrading performance?

Answer (score 2):

In our application we return an error code from the sproc. These error codes are integers which are fixed e.g. We return error code 10 if the user id being asked to update does not exist in the database. We use these error codes as keys in the resource files to define a standard error message against them.

We also have enume defined corresponding to these error codes just to make our lives easier

Comment: I understand, you are offloading handling the error messages to the application, and relying on the return error code to translate it into an human readable message.

Comment: Exactly. So the guys who document do not have look at multiple places and collate the error messages.